# selenium ide asserttextpresent date value

Tags: selenium

I keep gettting a [error] false in the IDE.This field has a date value which is 10/01/2013. In this field the date value is never constant. How do I verify this date value in the IDE.

Command    assertTextPresent
Target     id-date_value
Value      08/21/2013

Answer (score 0):

Use asserValue, that might help you

```
assertValue  |   id-date_value |  08/21/2013
```